# My values are not successfully inserting into my table. When I test the connection it is successful. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my index.php:

```
    private static function connection() {

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname="social";

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $conn;
    }
    public static function query($query, $params =array()) {
        $statement=self::connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
    }
```

And here is my login.php:

```
include('index.php');
if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
DB::query('INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :email)', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));
echo "Success!";
}
```

And here is my html form which is in the login.php under the php tags:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
    <form class="login.php" method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username ..." required><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password ..." required><br/>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="someone@gmail.com" required><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="createaccount" value="submit"> <br/>
    </form>
```

I am following a tutorial made five years ago. I am using Sequel Pro and my table is called users. I have four fields: id, username, password, and email.

Thanks for help

Comment: Your code assumes success, but you're doing nothing to trap any exceptions that might occur which would tell you what's gone wrong. Wrap your code in a `try...catch` block and find out what the exception is. Or, try looking at the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a non-existant method/property in your `query` function.
You are currently calling `self::connect->prepare` while a "connect" function/property is never declared in your code example.

I am assuming what you actually wanted to do is call the connection function and call the prepare function from the result connection object.

A potential fix might be to adjust the query function like so:

```php
    public static function query($query, $params =array()) {
        $statement=self::connection()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much